# haproxy not logging

Tags: logging, haproxy, rsyslog

I have configured rsyslog (CentOS 6.3) adding the `-c 0 -r` options and the line

```
local2.* /var/log/haproxy.log
```

and restarted `rsyslog` but all that happens is an `haproxy.log` gets created.  It is never written to.

Not quite sure how to troubleshoot this.

Below is my `haproxy.cfg` file.  Nothing else is configured to use `local2` according to grepping for it in `rsyslog.conf`.  My haproxy config is basically the default, just trying to get logging working first.

Comment: Please reformat your question so that it is readable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe haproxy only have syslog logging via UDP.  What is your log config line in haproxy.cfg?

Is it?

```
log 127.0.0.1 local2
```

If so, you'll need to enable the UDP server modules in the rsyslog configuration by uncommenting:

```
$ModLoad imudp.so
$UDPServerRun 514
```

Tip:  I run the following command on all my haproxy servers:

```
sudo sed -i 's/#$ModLoad imudp.so/$ModLoad imudp.so/' /etc/rsyslog.conf; sudo sed -i 's/#$UDPServerRun 514/$UDPServerRun 514/' /etc/rsyslog.conf; sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, for a dummy like me, who doesn't know that.. How would you recommend troubleshooting an issue like that?  How could I have seen that the UDP logging info was being blocked (aside from reading the rsyslog man pages)?

Comment: It was a while back for this problem (over a year ago), and I believe I solved it after reading one or some of the following:

- http://linuxadminzone.com/enable-or-fix-logging-for-haproxy-load-balancer/
- http://kvz.io/blog/2010/08/11/haproxy-logging/

Definitely read and re-read the haproxy config and rsyslog man pages.  Knowing that it's UDP to syslog logging from haproxy manual, I would have done a tcpdump to find who's at fault (whether haproxy or rsyslog) and go from there.  Command would be:

    tcpdump -i lo udp port 514

Comment: seems relevant: http://anhlqn.blogspot.com/2014/01/enable-haproxy-logging-on-centos_4363.html

Comment: I'm using rsyslog to try to gather haproxy logs, I have edited my conf files like you did, iptables is disabled, the log file is created; but nothing is written inside, even after a restart of both HAProxy and rsyslog ... I also have the good configuration in /etc/logrotate.d. I checked over and over the configuration, i'm in the same channel (local2) and I'm restrincting all this to the local loop (127.0.0.1). Did I miss something ? thx